# GraphQL "Cannot return null for non-nullable"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, graphql

Trying to make my first graphQL server, here's what I have written so far.

https://gist.github.com/tharakabimal/7f2947e805e69f67af2b633268db0406

Following error pops up on GraphQL when I try to filter the users by username.

[Error on GraphQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQSqz.png)

The error occurs in the users field in UserQueriesQL.js.

Is there anything wrong the way I pass arguments on the resolve functions?

```
user: {
type: UserType,
args: { 
  username: {
    name: 'username',
    type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)
  }
},
resolve: function(parentValue, args) {
  return User.find( args ).exec();
}
```

Comment: The error means you are returning `null`, but with `type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)` you declared that there may never be returned `null` for the username. Either return something else than `null`, or declare the type as `type: new GraphQLString()`

Comment: `User.find` will resolve to an array, but GraphQL is expecting an object instead. Please see Common Scenario #2 in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56319137/why-does-a-graphql-query-return-null/56319138#56319138).

Answer (score 6):

As I am beginner into GraphQL, even I ran into this issue. After going through each file individually I found that I forgot to import into my **resolvers**

```
import User from './User';
**import Post from './Post';**

const resolvers = [User, **Posts**];
```

Maybe this will help!

Answer (score 1):

```
user: {
type: UserType,
args: { 
  username: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) }
},
resolve: function(parentValue, args) {
  return User.find( args ).exec(); // User.find({username: 'some name'}).exec(); 
// will work as matches your mongoose schema
}
```

Previously, in the `args` you are providing an an `object` with nested object `username` so,

```
args: {  // this won't match your mongoose schema field as it's nested object
  username: {
    name: 'username',
    type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)
  }
}
```

so when the user queries and provides args then
 your args would be `{ username: { name: 'abcd' } }`

```
// args = {username: {name: 'abcd'}}
```

and `resolve()` is executing `User.find({username: {name: 'abcd'}}).exec();`

```
/* searching for username{} object, but
your mongoose schema is username: String */
```

which doesn't match your database fields, which will always return an empty array `[]`,also which will not match your GraphQL field type, as it is `GraphQLNonNull`

after viewing the `gist` the problem is with `rootquery`

the problem is with rootquery

```
let RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'RootQueryType',
    fields: () => ({
        users: { type:UserQueries.users, resolve: UserQueries.users }
        user: { type: UserQueries.user, resolve: UserQueries.user }
    })
});
```

Comment: I did the suggested changes, but still having the issue
https://gist.github.com/tharakabimal/c84ff21d6a6aa898cb3ccc02757867df

Comment: have you entered the username in the args

Comment: Yes https://gist.github.com/tharakabimal/1883dcb50322456fe81d37e9abc22daa

Comment: so do you have username `John` in `users` collection, put a gist and snapshot of the database

Comment: Here are the 3 users I have in my mongoDB
https://gist.github.com/tharakabimal/cdd58e7534fef268801142eb7ce4266c

Comment: the problem is with the rootQuery