# Nested resolvers with depth greater than 1

Tags: apollo, apollo-server

#### The Problem

Looking at this GraphQL query,

```
query {
    asset {
        name
        interfaces {
            created 
            ip_addresses {
                value
                network {
                    name
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I define a resolver for *just the **network*** field on ip_addresses?

#### My First Thought

Reading [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/resolvers/) the give examples of single nested queries, e.g

```
const resolverMap = {
  Query: {
    author(obj, args, context, info) {
      return find(authors, { id: args.id });
    },
  },
  Author: {
    posts(author) {
      return filter(posts, { authorId: author.id });
    },
  },
};
```

So I thought - why not just apply this pattern to nested properties?

```
const resolverMap = {  
  Query: {
      asset,
  },
  Asset: {
    interfaces: {
      ip_addresses: {
        network: () => console.log('network resolver called'),
      },
    },
  },
};
```

But this does not work, when I run the query - I do not see the console log.

#### Further Testing

I wanted to make sure that a resolver will always be called if its on root level of the query return type.

My hypothesis:

```
Asset: {
    properties: () => console.log('properties - will be called'), // This will get called
    interfaces: {
      created: () => console.log('created - wont be called'),
      ip_addresses: {
        network_id: () => console.log('network - wont be called'),
      },
    },

  },
```

And sure enough my console showed

```
properties - will be called
```

#### The confusing part

But somehow apollo is still using default resolvers for created and ip_addresses, as I can see the returned data in playground.

### Workaround

I can implement "monolith" resolvers as follows:

```
Asset: {
    interfaces,
  },
```

Where the interfaces resolver does something like this:

```
export const interfaces = ({ interfaces }) =>
  interfaces.map(interfaceObj => ({ ...interfaceObj, ip_addresses: ip_addresses(interfaceObj) }));

export const ip_addresses = ({ ip_addresses }) =>
  ip_addresses.map(ipAddressObj => ({
    ...ipAddressObj,
    network: network(null, { id: ipAddressObj.network_id }),
  }));
```

But I feel that this should be handled by default resolvers, as these custom resolvers aren't actually doing anything, but passing data down to another resolver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resolver map passed to the `ApolloServer` constructor is an object where each property is the name of a *type* in your schema. The value of this property is another object, wherein each property is a *field* for that type. Each of those properties then maps to a resolver function for that specified field.

You posted a query without posting your actual schema, so we don't know what any of your types are actually named, but assuming the `network` field is, for example, `Network`, your resolver map would need to look something like:

```
const resolver = {
  // ... other types like Query, IPAddress, etc. as needed
  Network: {
    name: () => 'My network name'
  } 
}
```

You can, of course, introduce a resolver for any field in the schema. If the field returns an object type, you return a JavaScript Object and can let the default resolver logic handle resolving "deeper" fields:

```
const resolvers = {
  IPAddress: {
    network: () => {
      return {
        name: 'My network name',
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Or...

```
const resolvers = {
  Interface: {
    ip_addresses: () => {
      return [
        { 
          value: 'Some value',
          network: {
            name: 'My network name',
          },
        },
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Where you override the default resolver just depends at what point the data returned from your root-level field no longer matches your schema. For a more detailed explanation of the default resolver behavior, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56319138/6024220).