# How to fix Apollo-GraphQL returning null for nullable field from mutation?

Tags: postgresql, graphql, babeljs, knex.js, apollo-server

I'm making a demo GraphQL API as a learning project which is using Apollo-server-express, Babel, Knex.js and PostgreSQL.

Query resolver went well but found a problem at mutation, returning null for non-nullable field.

```
// userMutation.js

import knex from '../libs/knex';

const userMutation = {
  create: function(data) {
    return knex('users')
      .insert(data)
      .returning('*');
  }
};
```

...

```
// Mutation.js

import userQuery from '../../queries/userQuery';
import userMutation from '../../mutations/userMutation';

const Mutation = {
  async createUser(parent, args, ctx, info) {
    const { data } = args;

    const emailTaken = userQuery.getByEmail(data.email);
    if (emailTaken) throw new Error('Email is taken');

    const user = {
      ...data
    };

    const result = await userMutation.create(user);

    console.log(result);
    return result;
  }
};

// typeDefs.js

type Mutation {
  createUser(data: CreateUserInput!): User
}
```

And I make a mutation:

```
mutation {
  createUser(
    data: { lastName: "One", email: "some@one.com", password: "okay123" }
  ) {
    email
  }
}
```

Then...

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field User.email.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 3,
          "column": 5
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "createUser",
        "email"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR"
      }
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "createUser": null
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: The shape of the data returned by the call to `insert` doesn't match your schema. According to your schema, the field should return a sigle object, but you are returning an array inside your resolver. Either change your schema, or grab the first item returned by `insert`. See [Common Scenario #2: Array Instead of Object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56319138/6024220) for more details.

Comment: Use console.log to find the shape of the returning object.  Then use Daniel's post to solve your problem.  You'll get better at this as you get more experience with GraphQL.

Comment: @DanielRearden Thanks, you're right. Resolver (knex) returning array, I changed the schema to `[User]` and it's fixed. @Preston Thanks, yes I needed to double-check the console.log output.