# How to use GraphQL subscription correctly?

Tags: javascript, graphql, graphql-js, koa, graphql-subscriptions

I have a GraphQL powered app. The query and mutation parts work well. I try to add GraphQL subscription.

The server GraphQL subscription part code is inspired by the demo in the readme of [apollographql/subscriptions-transport-ws](https://github.com/apollographql/subscriptions-transport-ws).

Please also check the comments in the code for more details.

```
import Koa from 'koa';
import Router from 'koa-router';
import graphqlHTTP from 'koa-graphql';
import asyncify from 'callback-to-async-iterator';
import { SubscriptionServer } from 'subscriptions-transport-ws';
import firebase from 'firebase-admin';
import { execute, subscribe } from 'graphql';
import { GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLString } from 'graphql';

const MeType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Me',
  fields: () => ({
    name: { type: GraphQLString },
    // ...
  }),
});

const listenMe = async (callback) => {
  // Below the firebase API returns real-time data
  return firebase
    .database()
    .ref('/users/123')
    .on('value', (snapshot) => {
      // snapshot.val() returns an Object including name field.
      // Here I tested is correct, it always returns { name: 'Rose', ... }
      // when some other fields inside got updated in database.
      return callback(snapshot.val());
    });
};

const Subscription = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Subscription',
  fields: () => ({
    meChanged: {
      type: MeType,
      subscribe: () => asyncify(listenMe),
    },
  }),
});

const schema = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: Query,
  mutation: Mutation,
  subscription: Subscription,
});

const app = new Koa();
app
  .use(new Router()
    .post('/graphql', async (ctx) => {
      // ...

      await graphqlHTTP({
        schema,
        graphiql: true,
      })(ctx);
    })
    .routes());

const server = app.listen(3009);

SubscriptionServer.create(
  {
    schema,
    execute,
    subscribe,
  },
  {
    server,
    path: '/subscriptions',
  },
);
```

I am using [Altair GraphQL Client](https://altair.sirmuel.design/) to test since it supports GraphQL subscription.

[image]

As the screenshot shows, it does get new data every time when the data changes in database.

However, `meChanged` is `null` and it does not throw any error. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: I don't know what alway means and you don't include the error message from the Network panel in Chrome Dev Tools so diagnosing your problem is difficult.  However, have you looked at this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56319137/why-does-a-graphql-query-return-null

Comment: @Preston Thanks! Just updated the title. I hope I could post Chrome console error message, but I haven’t started to build subscription part for client yet, since it is lack of document of using GraphQL subscription without any framework like Apollo. That is why I use Altair GraphQL Client as a start point to help me understand how GraphQL subscription works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally have a new library can do the work without full Apollo framework.

https://github.com/enisdenjo/graphql-ws

Here are the codes that I have succeed:

**Server (GraphQL Schema Definition Language)**

```
import { useServer } from 'graphql-ws/lib/use/ws';
import WebSocket from 'ws';
import { buildSchema } from 'graphql';

const schema = buildSchema(`
  type Subscription {
    greeting: String
  }
`);

const roots = {
  subscription: {
    greeting: async function* sayHiIn5Languages() {
      for (const hi of ['Hi', 'Bonjour', 'Hola', 'Ciao', 'Zdravo']) {
        yield { greeting: hi };
      }
    },
  },
};

const wsServer = new ws.Server({
  server, // Your HTTP server
  path: '/graphql',
});
useServer(
  {
    schema,
    execute,
    subscribe,
    roots,
  },
  wsServer
);
```

**Server (GraphQL.js GraphQLSchema object way)**

```
import { execute, subscribe, GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLSchema, GraphQLString } from 'graphql';
import { useServer } from 'graphql-ws/lib/use/ws';
import WebSocket from 'ws';
import { PubSub } from 'graphql-subscriptions';

const pubsub = new PubSub();

const subscription = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Subscription',
  fields: {
    greeting: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      resolve: (source) => {
        if (source instanceof Error) {
          throw source;
        }
        return source.greeting;
      },
      subscribe: () => {
        return pubsub.asyncIterator('greeting');
      },
    },
  },
});

const schema = new GraphQLSchema({
  query,
  mutation,
  subscription,
});

setInterval(() => {
  pubsub.publish('greeting', {
    greeting: 'Bonjour',
  });
}, 1000);

const wsServer = new ws.Server({
  server, // Your HTTP server
  path: '/graphql',
});
useServer(
  {
    schema,
    execute,
    subscribe,
    roots,
  },
  wsServer
);
```

**Client**

```
import { createClient } from 'graphql-ws';

const client = createClient({
  url: 'wss://localhost:5000/graphql',
});

client.subscribe(
  {
    query: 'subscription { greeting }',
  },
  {
    next: (data) => {
      console.log('data', data);
    },
    error: (error) => {
      console.error('error', error);
    },
    complete: () => {
      console.log('no more greetings');
    },
  }
);
```

*DISCLOSE: I am not associated with the library.*

Comment: I tried the first server ie,(Server (GraphQL Schema Definition Language)) and client code as it is to do one POC but i got following error :- "Subscription field must return Async Iterable. Received: {}.". Can you please let me know what i might be doing wrong as i'm a noob in graphql subscriptions

Comment: @sagg1295 check https://github.com/Hongbo-Miao/hongbomiao.com/blob/main/api/src/graphQL/queries/subscription.ts which might help you. It is a full working demo.

Comment: thanks for this. I want to clarify one thing in the above link you have used  graphql-subscriptions module. Is it necessary to do subscrption using this? Can't we just use graphql-ws, ws and graphql to do graphql susbcriptions?

As i was following code given on github page of graphql-ws. That was not working.
If you want i can share my github repo also if you can go through that it having just two files with logic

Comment: @sagg1295 the GraphQL Schema Definition Language way in the answer is also using `graphql-subscriptions` with `graphql-ws`, which is same.

Comment: but when i searched on google to do subscriptions in graphql i also this [graphql-subscriptions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-subscriptions) is separate thing than `graphql-ws`. Might i'be wrong. I thought both these are different approaches to do **susbcription in graphql**

Comment: @sagg1295 [graphql-ws](https://github.com/enisdenjo/graphql-ws) is same level with [subscriptions-transport-ws](https://github.com/apollographql/subscriptions-transport-ws). And [graphql-subscriptions](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-subscriptions) is different level thing.

Comment: how to handle variables in graphql subscription query passed by client at server here, can you give any example? tried seeing the documentation but not able to get this through

Comment: Your first example has `import WebSocket from 'ws';` but then you're doing `ws.Server`, which is correct?