# Apollo GraphQL query by ID return null

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql

I am learning GraphQL. Just made a simple API with Apollo-server-express with Knex.js and PostgreSQL.
I am facing a weird issue with querying user by ID, which return `null`.

This is user schema.

```
// user.schema.ts
  extend type Query {
    users: [User!]!
    user(id: ID): User
  }
```

This is user resolver.

```
// user.resolver.ts

    user: async (_: any, { id }: { id: number }, { dataSources }: any) => {
      await dataSources.userAPI.findOne({ id });
    }
```

This is datasource for user.

```
  async findOne({ id: idArg }: { id?: number } = {}) {
    const user: User = await this.knex('user')
      .where('id', idArg)
      .first();

    if (!user) return;
    console.log('@ USER HERE > ', user)
    return user;
  }
```

Note: `console.log` returns `user` with values.

```sh
@ USER HERE >  {
  id: 1,
  first_name: 'Some',
  last_name: 'One',
  email: 's@one.com',
  password: '$2a$08$C8PP992UaUX.T90mxm2yD.RKB.ZnAx.gzMpK796JQei4H1BvVNxBG',
  role: 'staff',
  is_active: false,
  created_at: 2019-09-17T16:03:06.949Z,
  updated_at: 2019-09-17T16:03:06.949Z
}
```

But somehow, it returns `null` in GraphQL playground.

```
{
  "data": {
    "user": null
  }
}
```

Does it relate to the caching? Because I tested some cache controls from Apollo docs. This is what I added in user `findOne` resolver before;

```
      // Add cache hints dynamically, this will hide result and return null
      // info.cacheControl.setCacheHint({ maxAge: 60, scope: 'PRIVATE' });
      await dataSources.userAPI.findOne({ id });
```

After that it started returning `null`, even after I removed it back. I have the same code for Post without testing that `info.cache`. Querying by Post ID is working fine.

Please help me.

Comment: nothing is returned from user.resolver.ts -> user function, that could be the issue.

Comment: A resolver must always return some value. Returning undefined will cause the field to resolve to null. See [Common Scenario #4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56319138/6024220).

Comment: Thanks! I don't know what went wrong, but now everything is fine after I rewrote the code.