# GraphQL returns Null in mongoose callback

Tags: mongoose, graphql

I have this mutation that returns as expected: id, url and description.

```
  post(parent, args, context, info) {

   const userId = getUserId(context);
   const user = await context.User.findOne({ _id: userId });

   return context.Link.create(
      {
        url: args.url,
        description: args.description,
        postedBy: userId
      },
 }
```

The problem is when I add this function that successfully update [Refs to children](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#refs-to-children)

```
async post(parent,args,context,info){

  const userId = getUserId(context);
  const user = await context.User.findOne({ _id: userId });

  return context.Link.create(
      {
        url: args.url,
        description: args.description,
        postedBy: userId
      },
      **function(error, createdLink) {
        user.links.push(createdLink._id);
        user.save(createdLink);
      }**
    );
}
```

Everything works perfect in mongoose and mongo, but graphQL returns null:

```
{
  "data": {
    "post": null
  }
}
```

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mix callbacks and Promises -- see Common Scenario #6 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56319137/why-does-a-graphql-query-return-null).

As explained [here in the docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html), passing a callback to the method means the result will be passed to the callback rather than being made available inside the `then` function of the resulting Query object. Just stick with Promises.

```
const link = await context.Link.create({
  url: args.url,
  description: args.description,
  postedBy: userId
});

user.links.push(link._id);
await user.save();

return link;
```

Comment: Now that I understood what I  was doing wrong, I was able to solve other problems I had with callbacks and promises. Thanks to you I will sleep well tonight!