# Why mongoose does not update document when using GraphQL?

Tags: mongoose, graphql

Something wrong here, do you know what?

```
switchEventSellingStarted: async(_, {name, sellingStarted}) => {
      Event.findOne({name: name}, function (err, event) {
        event.sellingStarted = sellingStarted;
        event.save();
        return event;
      });
    }
```

[image]

Comment: try adding return before Event.findOne?

Comment: Don't mix callbacks with Promises. Your resolver should always return a value or a Promise that will resolve to a value; otherwise, it will resolve to null. See [Common Scenario #6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56319138/6024220).