# Null value in GraphQL when trying to fetch data

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, graphql-js

Why am I receiving null value when I'm trying to fetch data from an external API?

This is my code

resolvers.js

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch'

export const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    getCrypto: async() => {
      const response = await fetch(`https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/top/totalvolfull?limit=10&tsym=USD`)
      return response.json();

    }
  },
};
```

schema.grapqhl

```
type CryptoCurrency {
  Id: ID
  Name: String
  FullName: String
  PRICE: Float
  LASTUPDATE: Float
}

type Query {
  getCrypto: CryptoCurrency
}
```

Screenshot of the error: 
[image]

Comment: What happens when you browse to the url used?

Comment: There's a mismatch between the shape of the object returned by the API you are getting your data from and the shape of your schema. See Common Scenario #1 and Common Scenario #3 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56319138/6024220).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your API returns an array, so should change your code like below.(for the first item)

```
 getCrypto: async () => {
        const response = await fetch(`https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/top/totalvolfull?limit=10&tsym=USD`)

        let data = await response.json()
        return data.Data[0].CoinInfo;
            }
```

Or if you intend to retrieve all names, first change your Query to accept as an array

```
type Query {
  getCrypto: [CryptoCurrency]
}
```

```
 getCrypto: async () => {
        const response = await fetch(`https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/top/totalvolfull?limit=10&tsym=USD`)

           let data = (await response.json()).Data.map(c => { return c.CoinInfo })


        return data

    }
```

Comment: Added ``return data.Data[0].CoinInfo```  and It worked Alex,  Thank you for the help

Comment: Your welcome, but be aware that Your API returns an array so you can have 0,1,2,..n index