# Graphql mutation succeeds but displays return fields as null

Tags: express, cassandra, graphql, graphql-mutation

I am using cassandra with graphql and express. On doing the mutation the database is updated, but it doesn't display the fields instead just shows null.
Upon using console.log to check the data and I can see it printed on terminal.

Code for mutation,

```
   const Mutation = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Mutation',
    fields: {
        add_user: {
            type: UserType,
            args: {
                username: { type : GraphQLString},
                email: { type : GraphQLString},
                name: { type : GraphQLString},
                password: { type : GraphQLString}
            },
            resolve(parent, args){
                const query = 'INSERT INTO users(username, email, name, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ';
                client.execute(query, [args.username, args.email, args.name, args.password])
                    .then(result => {
                        const query = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? ';
                        return client.execute(query, [args.username])
                            .then(result => {
                                console.log(result.rows[0]);
                                return result.rows[0];
                            });
                    });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

What I get

```
{
  "data": {
    "add_user": null
  }
}
```

Upon using this

```
mutation{
  add_user(username: "ABCdef", email: "abc.def@ddv.com", name: "ABCDEF", password: "abcdxyz"){
      username
        email
        name
  }
}
```

[On terminal I get the fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMGpP.png)

Update can be confirmed with

```
query{
  user(username: "ABCdef"){
    username
    email
    name
  }
}
```

which returns

```
{
  "data": {
    "user": {
      "username": "ABCdef",
      "email": "abc.def@ddv.com",
      "name": "ABCDEF"
    }
  }
}
```

Info about UserType

```
const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'User',
    fields: () => ({
        username: { type: GraphQLString },
        email: { type: GraphQLString },
        name: { type: GraphQLString },
        password: { type: GraphQLString }
    })
});
```

I want add_user to return the same but that's not happening for some reason

Comment: You're chaining your `then`s correctly, but your resolver does not return anything. See [Common Scenario #4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56319138/6024220).

Comment: Thank you so much! adding a return before client.execute solved the problem.